# How to multiply two colors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, colors, html5-canvas

The given parameters are r,g,b of two colors.

How can I multiply them? (Like blending mode->multiply in Photoshop)

Example:

color1:0,255,255

color2:255,255,0

multiplied:0,255,0

[image: example]

Comment: u have to use matrix multiplication for that

Comment: Please show us your code to give us an impression of the data structure you struggle with. Or do you ask for the multiply operator `*`?

Comment: I don't know the method of this effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the simple multiply formula, here is a javascript function that should work for RGB:

```
function multiply(rgb1, rgb2) {
    var result = [],
        i = 0;
    for( ; i < rgb1.length; i++ ) {
        ​result.push(Math.floor(rgb1[i] * rgb2[i] / 255));
    }
    return result;
}​
```

Using modern JavaScript:

```
const multiply = (rgb1, rgb2) => rgb1.map((c, i) => Math.floor(c * rgb2[i] / 255))
```

Here is a fiddle using background colors you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/unrLC/

[image]

Comment: just askin'... why the unorthodox declaration of `i`?

Comment: It’s a coding style — all variables declared at the head of the scope. Before ES6 `const` and `let`, you could only have variables which were scoped to a function or global, hoisted declarations permitted referencing a variable before it was initialized, and the same declaration could be made multiple times. Altogether this adds up to an easy way to introduce bugs. To address these issues, many people chose to restrict themselves to declaring all variables that would appear in a scope as the first statement in the function.

Answer (score 8):

[Here's the formula for multiplying colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Multiply) (as well as other blend mode formulas).

> Formula: Result Color = (Top Color) * (Bottom Color) /255

You can implement this very easily in JavaScript.

```
var newRed = red1 * red2 / 255;
var newGreen = green1 * green2 / 255;
var newBlue = blue1 * blue2 / 255;
```

Answer (score 3):

You translate the color components to a value between 0 and 1, then it's simple multiplication. Thanslate the result back to the range 0 to 255:

```
0, 255, 255  ->  0, 1, 1
255, 255, 0  ->  1, 1, 0

0*1 = 0, 1*1 = 1, 1*0 = 0

0, 1, 0  ->  0, 255, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the aim is to multiply color ranges from 0 to 255. Reduce them to a range of [0, 1], multiply them, and expand them again:

```
color_new = ( (color_1 / 255) * (color_2 / 255) ) * 255
color_new = color_1 * color_2 / 255
```